# Paste string list as class

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I was searching for "paste string list as class" like as "Paste XML as Classes".

For clarification, I have a long list of properties name of class & I am going make this as a class.
For example, I have below :

```
First_Name
Gender
Surname
ErrorCode
ErrorMessage
.....
```

And I want this below:

```
public string First_Name { get; set; }
public string Gender { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
```

......

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Block Selection` trick in Visual Studio. Just hold your `ALT key` on your keyboard and select the part (by mouse drag) you want to paste your code, then paste it.

This what it looks light when you highlight it:

[image]

And here what it looks like when I paste it on highlighted code:

[image]

For additional details, you can refer to this link: [Visual Studio Tips and Tricks.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn320181.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: If you want to do a visual studio based solution, this is definitely the route I usually take.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any visual studio solution but I got a regular expression solution (using Notepad++).

The solution is below:
Find all words using "**(.*)**" and replace the desired one.

Find What: `(.*)`

Replace with: `public string \1 { get; set; }`

Like the below picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sublimetext.com/3

Sublime Text is far better than any solution suggested here.